# C++ object pointer changing location

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I have a function that expects two pointers, one to a string object and one to a custom KCData object:

```
void KCConverter::dataToHexStringBuf(std::string *hexStringBuf, KCData *data) {
    char hexBuf[2];
    size_t position = data->getPosition();
    size_t length = data->getLength();
    uint8_t *copy = new uint8_t[data->getLength()];
    memcpy(copy, data->bytes, data->getLength());

    uint8_t current;
    for (size_t i = position; i < length; i++) {
        std::cout << "Reading char " << i << std::endl;
        current = copy[i];
        sprintf(hexBuf, "%02X", current);
        hexStringBuf->push_back(hexBuf[0]);
        hexStringBuf->push_back(hexBuf[1]);
    }
    data->setPosition(data->getLength());
}
```

However the value of the KCData-pointer is changing in the for-loop:

First iteration:
[image: First iteration]

Second iteration:
[image]

Third iteration:
[image]

However, if I uncomment the line `sprintf(hexBuf, "%02X", current);`, the pointer doesn't change anymore. But why is `sprintf` changing the pointer-address of `data`????

P.S.: If you vote my question down, it would be nice to learn the reason so I can improve my question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are overflowing `hexBuf[]`:

```
char hexBuf[2]; // 2 bytes long
...
    sprintf(hexBuf, "%02X", current); // Writing 3 bytes
```

You have to include the nul-character `\0` in the length of the output string. Solution is to make `hexBuf[]` at least 3 bytes long.